# Table view scrolling the text filed value not persist 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` some `UITextField` on Table view cell. `UITextField`s in user enter some values on the text field and then scrolling table view.the value on text field is not persist. below code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {  
return 100; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier    = @"Cell";
static NSString *CellIdentifierFirst    = @"CellFirst";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierFirst];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

NSArray *cellSubs = cell.contentView.subviews;
for (int i = 0 ; i < [cellSubs count] ; i++) {
    [[cellSubs objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

UITextField * textFieldRounded = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 150, 40)];
textFieldRounded.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
textFieldRounded.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
textFieldRounded.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];  
textFieldRounded.placeholder = @"Type here"; 
textFieldRounded.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
textFieldRounded.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;   
textFieldRounded.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;  
textFieldRounded.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  
textFieldRounded.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; 
textFieldRounded.delegate = self;   
[cell.contentView addSubview:textFieldRounded];
return cell;
}
```

So Please help me everyone

Comment: Where are you adding the text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to maintain a mutable array for all the rows. You will have to store the text in that array every time the text is changed and set the text from the array when `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

Answer (score 3):

I have same feature in one of my apps and I used below code to accomplish that and I never had this kind of problem.

First of all you need to store all your textField value temporary in Array. Make array like this.

```
arrTemp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@""],nil];
```

Then Give all textField tag = indexPath.row;

After that You need to replace textField value in below two methods.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
   [arrTemp replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
 [arrTemp replaceObjectAtIndex:textField.tag withObject:textField.text];
}
```

At Last You need to set that value in cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource Method. So that whenever user scroll tableview it set previous value from temp array. Like this.

```
cell.txtEntry.text = [arrTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It might possible I forgot some of the code to paste here. So if you have any problem please let me know.